# PHP PDO: Execute a Query using a stored function in WHERE clause

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to execute a query and one of the conditionals in the SELECT is a MySQL function.

The stored function receive two parameters and return 1/0 values, depending on the result.

When I use the app Navicat executing the query, it works fine but when executed in PHP not.

This is the query:

```
SELECT g.* 
FROM PR6015.georefencia as g 
WHERE g.code='C' 
  AND isPointInRegion('".$lat."', '".$lon."', g.G, g.K)
```

This query is invoked using PDO.

Is there something missing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I guess, its data issue. Function `isPointInRegion` might be returning `NULL` depending upon the value of `g.G` or `g.K`

Comment: As I mentioned, if I execute the function in Navicat, it works. The values of g.G and g.K are float values.